# Displaying dynamic UTC clock time on JSP screen

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, clock, runnable

I want to access the string variable in run() method and display the value on jsp screen. Please note that the value , which string variable in run() method holds, changes every 1 second as per the below code. Hence my requirement is to display the value on screen and change the value dynamically.

```
                              (OR)
```

To put it simple, all I am trying to display is the UTC clock time ,which changes every one second, on JSP screen.

```
public class Clock implements Runnable {

    JLabel jb;

//Constructor takes the clock JLabel
    public Clock(JLabel jb) {
        this.jb = jb;
    }


    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                //Thread sleeps & updates ever 1 second, so the clock changes every 1 second.
                jb.setText(timeNow());
                String dynaStr= timeNow();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
      public String timeNow() {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    TimeZone z = c.getTimeZone();
    int offset = z.getRawOffset();
    if(z.inDaylightTime(new Date())){
        offset = offset + z.getDSTSavings();
    }
    int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;

    System.out.println("offset: " + offsetHrs);
    System.out.println("offset: " + offsetMins);

    c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (-offsetHrs));
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-offsetMins));

    System.out.println("GMT Time: "+c.getTime());
    return c.getTime().toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Use javascript for this not java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript not java.  An example is:

```
var myVar=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);
function myTimer() {
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date.toISOString();
}
```

demo being your div or whatever your using for display.

Here is fully functional code just copy and paste into text document and change extension from txt to html or (jsp).  Then double click to run in browser.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);
var counter = 0;
function myTimer() {
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date.toISOString();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <span id="demo"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use `date.toUTCString()` which will give you the same thing just different format.

Comment: @ brso05 .... I have to display the UTC time for which I must write some code in run method. How would I execute this logic using javascript? please advise

Comment: @KishorePaparthi There you go I edited it to display current date and time! Hope this helps!

Comment: I would like to get the value of string variable which is present in   run method. I mean, the counter variable in your javascript code should get the value from string variable dynaStr from run() method of my code.

Comment: @KishorePaparthi You would have to refresh the page each time which is not something you want to do.  If all you are trying to do is display current date and time then you should use the code above.  If you are trying to accomplish something else then maybe I can help you do it in javascript but passing variables from java to javascript/html usually requires page refresh which isn't very efficient.

Comment: @KishorePaparthi did you try running the edited code I posted.  It will give the users current date and time every second.

Comment: Your code works fine to display the system time. But I want to display the UTC time which remains the same irrespective of country (India, UK, USA etc.,) To achieve this, i have written a code in run method. But the problem is I want to access this value from run  method in javascript or jsp.

Comment: You can't without refresh reloading page every second.  Why not convert time to utc time in javascript.

Comment: @ brso05 .. Though my question is to access run method variable in jsp. Your responses are helpful and made me to think of some other alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: @KishorePaparthi I edited my code again to convert to UTC time try it out let me know what you think.

Comment: @ brso05 .. I want to have this code in javascript.             public String timeNow() {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone z = c.getTimeZone();
    int offset = z.getRawOffset();
    if(z.inDaylightTime(new Date())){
        offset = offset + z.getDSTSavings();
    }
    int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;
    System.out.println("offset: " + offsetHrs);
    System.out.println("offset: " + offsetMins);

    c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (-offsetHrs));
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-offsetMins));
    return c.getTime().toString();
}

Comment: @KishorePaparthi If you look at my update code you will see I call .toISOString on the date which should give you your UTC time.

Comment: @ brso05... can you pls help me with code for converting the system time to UTC in javascript. Since it includes offset calculation , I wrote my code in java method.

Comment: @KishorePaparthi Ya I posted the code to convert to UTC time.  Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @ brso05...perfect. It worked for me. no need of any java class or run method. Though my question was different you understood my requirement and gave me the correct answer. much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KishorePaparthi No problem man glad I could help! Also there is a toUTCString() method you can use too instead of toISOString() method which will give you same thing but different format.